# ++v2 output to stop before my first variable

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm trying a very basic C++ exercise:

***Write a program that prompts the user for two integers. Print each number in the range specified by those two integers.***

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Write two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The numbers between " << v1 << " and " << v2 << " are: " << std::endl;

    while (v1 > v2)
    {
        std::cout << ++v2 << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```

My output shows like this:

```
Write two numbers: 
10
5
The numbers between 10 and 5 are: 
6
7
8
9
10
```

**And my questions is, how do I output just from 6 to 9, without the 10?**

I'm with the basics, so I don't need for or loops or other things more advanced, just a `while` and `++v2`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, it will be the same, just changed positions, but the result is the same, thanks for answering by the way!

Comment: `while (++v2 < v1) std::cout << v2 << std::endl;`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Evg that was the answer! That was a great help, thanks!

Comment: You should probably also consider the case where the user enters the smaller number first.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will, I'm just sorting out my doubts before continuing, I don´t thing the next part will be that difficult, but thanks you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally added this code in order to work and to read both cases as a comment suggested before:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Write two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The numbers between " << v1 << " and " << v2 << " are: " << std::endl;

    while (v2 < v1 && ++v2 < v1)
    {
        std::cout << v2 << std::endl;
    }

    while (v1 < v2 && ++v1 < v2)
    {
        std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
    }

}
```

If it is too newbie, let me know, maybe there is another way to make it look simpler (just with `while`).

Answer (score 0):

```
while(v1 != v2 - 1)
{
    std::cout << ++v1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, still not into that kind of operators, but will take a look when I'm there!